# Full Screen background slideshow that allows image placements

Tags: jquery, html, slider

Ok i have tried 2 different full screen/full width slideshow .

http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

but those don't work as i need them to.

I'm looking for a full width content slider, that adjust with screen size and allows me to place images above it.

Something like -----------> Taylorswift.com

See how there is a background slideshow and she can place images on top on the background with each slide.

When i tried doing that with those two sliders it didn't work. With the first slider the image just stretched. and the second slider isn't an html slider.

I even tried adjusting the css myself.

Anyone know where i can find a slider like the one on ----> Taylorswift.com

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking at is the there in Royal Slider. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

you can check various implementation here http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/templates/

I use this slider and it's kinda cool. I am no way affiliated to them just make sure you check other alternatives before buying